# Building a docker image without stack

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack

I have haskell project and I can build a docker image on my MacOS using `stack image build` with the following settings in `stack.yml`.

```
resolver: lts-11.1

packages:
- .

docker:
  enable: true
image:
  container:
    base: "gcr.io/myapp/myapp-base"
    name: "gcr.io/myapp/myapp-api"
```

However, our CI server doesn't have `stack`, it only has docker and docker-compose. Is it possible for `stack` to generate the `Dockerfile` file, so that I can just build an image with that on our CI server without installing `stack`?

Comment: Or, is it possible to build a docker image by running `stack image container` in a docker container?

Comment: (N.B.: The tag for Stack is [haskell-stack], as opposed to just [stack].)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Stack doesn't have any command to generate `Dockerfile`. Usually I write one myself for CI. Their base image is [stack-build](https://hub.docker.com/r/fpco/stack-build/). A recent docker file for the yesod app which I wrote:

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-9.20

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN stack build
RUN stack install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["stack", "exec", "twilio-demo"]
```

Note that in the above method, the docker image contains the Stack build tool.

Comment: This works, just that the `stack-build` image is huge (~7G).

Comment: Yeah, But the current CI I'm using, seems to cache the base image after first time usage. ( I don't remember doing anything specifically for it )